# Changing CSS element using Javascript or change using CSS <noscript>

Tags: javascript, html, css

This has been asked before and i've read several previous questions but for some reason the solutions are not working for me, i'm sure this is pretty simple, i just know basically 0 HTML, CSS and JS.

Bit of background, i have a Python program that outputs an HTML file, this has some basic Javascript and CSS in it in order to create a collapsible. The default of the collapsible is all collapsed. However sometimes i need to view this page on a browser that has javascript disabled (eg: when you open a HTML file emailed to an iOS device). In order to that i need the collapsible to be all un-collapsed if Javascript can't be executed.  Here's what i have and what i've tried so far:

```html
<head>
    <style>
    .collapsible {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    }
    .content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <h2 class="collapsible">Here's a section to open</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Here's some revealed content</p>
        </div>
        <h2 class="collapsible">Here's another section to open</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Here's more revealed content</p>
        </div>
</body>


<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

  </script>
```

I've tried adding the following to :

`document.getElementsByClassName("content").style.maxHeight = "0";`

and setting the CSS of content.max-height to 100 by default, so that if javascript can't run the max-height is kept at 100 and all content divs are shown. This doesn't work Edge debug tools say:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'maxHeight')*

I also tried adding the following in after the main style tag to override the original CSS if javscript isn't supported:

```html
   <noscript>
    <style>
   .content {
    max-height: 100;
    }
    </style>
    </noscript>
```

That didn't work either

Comment: try ```<noscript><style>.content {max-height: 100%; overflow:visible;}</style></noscript>``` i think that will gonna work.

Comment: not exactly related, but `.collapsible` may benefit from the styling `user-select: none;`. This will prevent it from being highlighted.

Comment: Thanks @naxsi it appears the % was the magic sauce to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not having the bug occur with your code. Maybe the placement of your noscript tag was causing issues? Try this code and see if you have issues with it. It may also be a lack of html / css support in your email client if this is intended to be used in email.

I changed a couple things that were mainly cosmetic/readability/preference changes. Using the forEach method instead of a loop. Moving the style & script tags into the body as they might be used for email components.

```html
<body>
  <style>
    .collapsible {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .content {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
  </style>
  
  <h2 class="collapsible">Here's a section to open</h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Here's some revealed content</p>
  </div>
  <h2 class="collapsible">Here's another section to open</h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Here's more revealed content</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    const allColls = document
      .querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
    
    allColls.forEach(coll => {
      coll.addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.target.classList.toggle("active");
        const content = e.target.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight)
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        else 
          content.style.maxHeight = 
            content.scrollHeight + "px";
      });
    });
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <style>
      .content {
        max-height: 100;
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works for me in the given form, i'm still having issues porting it into my main HTML ode, not the simplified version i presented.  There must be something else causing issues, but at least i know core idea works, so i can build from there.

Comment: Update:  Combining your suggestions with @naxsi remark of using 100% vs 100 seems to work great.  Just for reference the HTML isn;t embedded as HTML in the email body, its attached as an .html file attachment. iOS allows you to view/render this attached HTML file but wont let JS run, i assume for security reasons.